# Text block over a banner's image

Tags: html, css

I have the following structure

```
<li class="hero-dna"></li>
```

this `<li>` contains an image as a bakgound, and I want to add the following text

`<font class="banner-title1">Bla bla bla</font>`

on top of the banner as  a layer. but if I put it before, it sits behind it.

Here is the page: https://genomeqatar-dev.qcri.org/

Is there a wayto do that?

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: did u try adding z-index to the banner text ?

Comment: Why dont you go with title tags if it should be a title then do the markup properly :) <h1></h1>.... <h2></h2> ... whatever

Comment: If you could provide a working code snippet in your question it would be so much easier to answer

Comment: <font>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used. There are *thousands* of "text on image" questions on SO...did you even try searching first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use position absolute;()

```
li{
   position: relative;
}
li font{
  position: absolute;
   top:0;
}//however,I suggest you can use "<span>" <h1>-<h6>" to replace <font>,beacuse html5 don't recommend use <font>
```

Comment: and should I add the <font> inside the <li>?

Comment: however,I suggest you can use <span> <h1>-<h6> to replace <font>,beacuse html5 don't recommend use <font>

Comment: So this was after all partly the solution, it was missing a z-index higher than the li as well: z-index:3 in this case.